# how to setup templates in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, templates, resharper, visual-studio-2012

I am working with Visual Studio 2012 and I would like to create some templates ie. when I create a new C# class, javascript file etc I would like a custom template in place so that it has the standard company copyright header, layout etc.

I have done this before as part of ItemTemplates and ProjectTemplates within VS, but it gets kinda messy. Is there an easier way of doing this?

I work with resharper within VS, so any way this could ease the process.

I would also like to do similar for SQL Management Studio, I am presuming the template process is similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup file header text in resharper options: `Resharper -> Options -> Code Editing -> File Header Text`. After this create formater or edit existing in `Resharper -> Options -> Code Editing -> Code Cleanup` and enable there option `update file header`. So if you run formater after that, it will add the header. To run formater you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. Additionaly formater reformat your code according to code style configuration. You can read more about this [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_formatting.html). 

But unfortunately I don't know is there a way to share this with SQL Management Studio.